Palantir Foundry Data Connection not Exporting All Parquet File parts
I have multiple data connection jobs set up within foundry that exported to an AWS S3 bucket using the Magritte Task.  They worked fine for a few years, then at the beginning of June they stopped working for datasets with more than 3 parquet file parts.  As an example, if a dataset was only made up of 1 parquet file no problem on the export.  Once the parquet had more than 3 parquet file parts it would only export 3 of the parts and then throw this error:
message: com.palantir.logsafe.exceptions.SafeRuntimeException: Attempting to export to the same path a second time:
Anyone have a clue of what this means?

The message likely means that the target path of the file you are exporting is clashing with the first file that was already exported.
Do you have a rewritePaths configuration setup on the Data Connection Task that would rename the file on the fly ?
If there was no change to the sync configuration or something else, then it might be worth discussion that with the support.
As a side-note, Tasks are considered legacy and there should be alternatives.
